# Django HttpResponseRedirectwith URL Variables handling

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I created an input form to get the data into web and use the inputs for an AP call.
When I want t refresh the page, there is a popup asking if you want to refresh the input. This is very annoying. 
The solution was to use HttpResponseRedirect, which workout nicely, but it's throwing away all the inputs. Then the though would be to use variable in the URL with "URL?rds=2".
How do you get the input variables through the HttpResponseRedirect to the same site? 
And also how to get variables from URL to input and from input to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

HTML input definition:

```
    <form action="{% url 'page' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="number" value="{{request.GET.rds}}" name='rds'>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

views.py:

Getting the data from the URL input

```
if 'rds' in request.GET.keys():
        radius = request.GET.get('rds')
    else: 
        request.GET.rds = '3'
        radius = '3'
```

Redirecting input if user pressed. Add more variables with "&" if needed.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        radius = request.POST.get('rds')
        redirect_link = request.path_info + '?rds=' + str(radius)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_link)
```

This will redirect the radius to the same page and will put rds as a get attribute, which will be fatched by the if method.

Afterwards you can use the data with.

```
context = {'radius': radius}
return render(request=request, template_name='realestate/page.html', context = context)
```

I hope this is helpfull. Maybe there is also a way better solution then this.